# How to quickly choose the option marked with [?] in helm

Tags: helm

For example I want to rename a file hello1 to hello. In dired mode, after dired-rename (R), I typed hello, but the focus was on hello1, so I used C-p to get to the option hello and then enter to finish the renaming.

How do I do it with just one key binding like C-m or C-j?

Comment: What version of helm are you using? It looks like this issue has been fixed about ten days ago by [this commit](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/commit/4740cb3f77f93fb79b7892b7d4c1fca0a505929a) and it works fine for me.

Comment: I think it's not that issue. In my case, hello matches hello1, so hello1 is the real candidate. There is another line above it marked with [?], normally I use C-p to get to it and enter. The same result after I updated helm with MELPA version.

Comment: according to that commit, helm shouldn't select the real candidate initially when running dried-rename. If it doesn't work for you, then feel free to submit an issue to helm. By the way, don't forget to restart your emacs after upgrading helm with package.el, since sometimes it is necessary.